# Use Virtual Scroll in image gallery

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to implement a virtual scroll in my image gallery. My problem is that the implementation doesn't work correctly. First, the elements are displayed in vertical position, when in fact they should respect the horizontal breakpoints and only then respect the vertical scroll. Second, with the scroll elements appear with huge spacing.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? thanks

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-virtual-scrolling-xmqzck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**HTML**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="viewMode" style="height:100%; width:100%">
  <div id="tab2" *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div
      style="margin-left: 16px; margin-right: 16px;height:100%; width:100%"
      class="first"
    >
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="
          arrayDeNomesCategorias.length == 0 ||
          arrayDeNomesCategorias == undefined
        "
      >
        <ul
          class="mdc-image-list my-image-list"
          style="height:100%; width:100%"
        >
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
            itemSize="50"
            style="height:100%; width:100%"
          >
            <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let i of images; let j = index">
              <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
                  <img
                    src="https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/{{
                      i + 1
                    }}.jpg"
                    class="mdc-image-list__image"
                  />
                </div>
              </li>
            </ng-container>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

[image: img1]

**Correct, but without the implemented scroll :(**

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-virtual-scrolling-csgzae?file=src/app/app.component.scss).

Your problem was mainly css and there seem to have been (at least) 2 problems:

1. Your are giving `.mdc-image-list__item` class `min-height: 400px` and `max-height: 400px`. That basically means that all your `.mdc-image-list__item` containers will have 400px height (so height: auto is kind of useless). Removing this will remove the white space between your images.
2. If you want to have scroll as well as elements on the same page you should use a flex container with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

In order to do this I used the following snippet (for your case):

```
:host ::ng-deep .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

You can read more about host and ng-deep [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). But please be aware that according to [this article (and not only)](https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg) is recommended to avoid using it in recent version of angular. For the sake of simplicity I used it on your example but you might want to avoid it in production.

3. (extra) : As a small improve I also removed the duplicated `margin: 10px; height: auto; max-height: 400px;` properties from `.mdc-image-list__item` media queries (and only leaved the initial one with no media query). It will be applied anyway since there isn't anything to overwrite it and just changing just the with on the media queries should be enough.

Comment: Perfect, thank you !!

Comment: You're welcome! :)